# Javascript scope referencing outer object

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, encapsulation, joose

Basically, I use a meta-class framework called [Joose](http://joose.it) for Javascript that allows me to make use of a more elegant class syntax - but I don't know how I might go about referencing the scope of the object from within deeper methods of the class declaration. I also use require.js for dependemcy management...

Here's an example class definition:

```
   define([
      'jquery',
      'handlebars',
   ], function($, Handlebars){

      var MyClass = Class("MyClass", {

         //inheritance         
         isa: SuperClass,

         //instance vars
         has: {

            hello:{
               is: 'r',
               init: 'Hi There!',
            },

            someVarToBeSetUsingAjax:{
               is: 'rw',
               init: false,
            },
         },

         //methods
         methods: {

            init: function () {

               var self = this;
               self.getAjaxVar();

            },

            getAjaxVar: function() {

               var self = this;

               //HOW CAN I REFERENCE 'self' THROUGHOUT MY OBJECT?

               $.get('ajax/test.html', function(response) {
                 self.someVarToBeSetUsingAjax = response.value;
               });
            },

            //lots more methods...

         }
    });

   return MyClass;

});
```

Ok, so my issue is - in the AJAX function I have to write var self = this to get my object into the scope of the AJAX call - no problem. But, I find myself doing this for  almost every single method in my class declaration! How can I reference self in all of the methods in a clean and efficient way? I know you can use scope in AJAX by setting a parameter, assume it's not just AJAX but other functions that close the scope to the outside.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you nest a function, you have to think about `this`.  But if you dont nest a function, or that function doesn't use `this` you don't need to think about it.

```
        init: function () {
           var self = this;
           self.getAjaxVar();
        },
```

So in this case it's not necessary. This is exactly the same:

```
        init: function () {
           this.getAjaxVar();
        },
```

But here:

```
        getAjaxVar: function() {
           var self = this;

           $.get('ajax/test.html', function(response) {
             self.someVarToBeSetUsingAjax = response.value;
           });
        },
```

You create an inner function, and you want a reference to the original value of `this`, so you do have to alias `this` to `self` to make it accessible.

There isn't a way to fix `this` to a value from everywhere in your class.

---

That said, you do have some options.

`Function.prototype.bind()` can help.

```
var func = function() { return this.name };
var obj = { name: 'Bob' };
var boundFunc = func.bind(obj);
boundFunc(); // 'Bob'
```

`bind` will return a new function with `this` always set to a specific object.

So:

```
        getAjaxVar: function() {
           $.get('ajax/test.html', function(response) {
             this.someVarToBeSetUsingAjax = response.value;
           }.bind(this));
        },
```

Note this isn't supported in all browsers, you may need a shim for the old ones.

Or just get used to `self = this`.

---

I want to give a minor nod to coffeescript as well, because it supports declaration of functions that dont change the context when run.

```
obj = {
  name: "bob"
  sayHello: ->
    doSomeAjax({
      success: =>
        alert "successfully made " + this.name + " say hello!"
    })
}

obj.sayHello()
```

`->` makes a normal function. But the fat arrow `=>` will instead preserve the value of `this` inside and outside the function. It's very very handy in callbacks within instance methods.  When compiled to JS, it basically does a `self = this` alias for you, using `self` within the inner function everytime to reference `this`. It's pretty slick.

In plain JS though, the most common pattern is simply `self = this`, stick to it.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the first bit, I was just trying to illustrate. Thanks for the help though, think i'll just have to get used to it!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `this`.  You only need to create a closure (which you do with the `var self = this;` when you have a function which will be called external to the object. (as you do here with the return from the ajax call).

There is no other way to create a closure.

---

To be clear (since some will jump on any slight technical hand waving), you don't "need" to create a closure.  But I think you should -- JavaScript was designed to work with closures, they work well and they are well understood by other JavaScript programmers.

Comment: @Bergi - Thus there are not other ways to do closure (your first comment).

Comment: Oops, I must've misread that as "*There is no other way [to achieve that]* than *to create a closure.*"

Comment: @Bergi - NP, as you can see your comment prompted me to create the 2nd section which is a vast improvement over my original answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> I find myself doing this for almost every single method in my class declaration! How can I reference self in all of the methods in a clean and efficient way?

You cannot. The value of `self`, the instance referenced by `this`, is only known on calling the method.

You only could work around that and use one common `self` variable if you declared that in the constructor (your `init` method?) and created all the callback functions there as well. Might not be the most memory-efficient method, though:

```
return Class("MyClass", {
     // …

     methods: {
         init: function () {
             var self = this;
             this.ajaxVarCallback = function(response) {
                 self.someVarToBeSetUsingAjax = response.value;
             };
             // and other functions that use "self"

             this.getAjaxVar();
         },
         getAjaxVar: function() {
             $.get('ajax/test.html', this.ajaxVarCallback);
         },
         // …
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from always keeping all instances of MyClass in scope (or as a global variable), I don't see any solutions. However, you could do away with having to declare `self` everywhere by using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(response) {
  this.someVarToBeSetUsingAjax = response.value;
}.bind(this));
```

This isn't limited to $.get(), you can use it everywhere you're using callback functions.